# Не работает отправка сообщений через telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/user/Desktop/telegram bot (1)/import telethon.py", line 4, in <module>
    from telethon import TelegramClient
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\telethon\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .client.telegramclient import TelegramClient
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\__init__.py", 
line 12, in <module>
    from .telegrambaseclient import TelegramBaseClient
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\telegrambaseclient.py", line 12, in <module>
    from ..crypto import rsa
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\telethon\crypto\__init__.py", 
line 6, in <module>
    from .aes import AES
  File "C:\Users\Marina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\telethon\crypto\aes.py", line 
9, in <module>
    import pyaes
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaes'
```

> До подключения прокси к коду все было нормально , потом почему то
> понадобился pyaes хотя в коде он никак не используется, задаюсь
> вопросом как это решить? (python 3.8.0)

Comment: И еще примечание на компьютере уже установлен pyaes но при попытке импорта выдает ошибку